# Fortran77: Checking if character array index is empty

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran77, character-arrays

I have a character array **names(10)*6**. I'm looping through I = 1:10 and writing the values of **names(I).**

The problem is that **names** periodically is missing values, and if thats the case for a particular **names(I)**, I want to skip it.

I was trying to do something like this.

```
   IF(names(I) .NE. 0) THEN 
        WRITE(4,202) names(I)   
    ENDIF
```

I got an error telling me I'm dumb for comparing characters to 0. That makes sense.
What should I compare it to? Empty spaces like this? How do I check if its not defined or empty after I declared space for it?

```
IF(mychar(I) .NE. '      ') THEN 
     WRITE(4,202) names(I)  
ENDIF
```

The goal is to only issue the write command if there is actually something there. :-)

Edit Note: I may not initialize this array. I am wondering what the default value for an undefined declared index is, or if there is a function to check if a character array index is empty.

Comment: Why not initialize it to an empty string prior to usage? Then, you can do the check you proposed...

Comment: Describe the situation in more detail in the question. Show what you really want to achieve, not just what you mistakenly think is the right way how to do it.

Comment: fortran strings are blank padded, so `LEN_TRIM(string).eq.0` , `string.eq.'' `, and `string.eq.'            '` are all equivalent.  ( And all will likely be false if the string was never initialised. )

Comment: Response to the "Edit note".  By "undefined" I assume that you mean "uninitialized".  Fortran provides no default values for uninitialized variables.  You should initialize the variable before comparing it. However, when you assign to a string with a shorter string, the remaining trailing characters are filled with blanks.  Perhaps that it what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the intrinsic `len_trim` function.  As always Read The Fortran Manual.

Comment: I think this will be an effective way to check if it has been defined, I will try it out. Thank you for the response.